# Visual C++ GUI Problems when trying to integrate existing C++ Code

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++

I have a fully functioning classes and functions for a program I need to build. I'm using Visual C++ to put together the GUI, and use the existing classes and functions in the event handlers of the GUI to manage the program.

The problem is I'm having a really hard time putting together the C++ code with the GUI. For some reason even though I've included the headers, things like Linked lists and stuff but it doesn't recognize the functions or the global variables.

When creating a Windows Forms Application, where do I put the classes and functions (that are not GUI related)? Is there a special place where I need to declare them?

Any help is appreciated as I'm pretty lost at the moment

EDIT: I guess a different way of asking this questions is this; in Visual C++, when you are creating a Windows Forms Application, where do you define and declare the classes and functions that the GUI will be using?

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that you're getting link errors?

You should be able to add files to the project.  Have you added the .cpp files to your project?  The .obj files?

Comment: no, we have no .obj files.. But let's say in a view, i need to print the contents of a linklist that gets created in a function, when i call it within an event handler in the forms class, it says that it's not defined. I tried adding a separate .cpp file, and also try to add the functions into the Form class but no go.

Am i supposed to be doing something with a .obj file?

Comment: What says that what isn't defined?  It sounds now as though the object has the wrong scope.  Please post the actual code and the actual error message